# how to use multiple decorators in python?

Tags: python, python-decorators

can some one tell me which fuction is being called first and which one is called at last
here inner() function return fun(a,b) but instead of execution it is passing parameter to function iny() . how that's possible?

```
def deco(fun):
    def inner(a,b):
        if a<b:
            a,b=b,a
        print(a,b)
        return fun(a,b)
    return inner
def smart(fun):
    def iny(a,b):
        a,b=a+1,b+1
        print(a,b)
        return fun(a,b)
    return iny

'''@deco
@smart'''
def div(a,b):
    return a/b
di=deco(smart(div))(4,8)
print(di)
```

Answer (score 1):

Your code is essentially the same as:

```py
def div(a, b):
    return a/b

def smart(a, b):
    a,b=a+1,b+1
    print(a,b)
    return div(a,b)

def deco(a, b):
    if a<b:
        a,b=b,a
    print(a,b)
    return smart(a,b)

di=deco(4,8)
print(di)
```

In your code `fun` from `inner` is set to `iny` from `smart` and `fun` from `iny` is set to `div`.

To explain the order I give you a simplified example with functions named `outer` and `inner` for their respective positions:

```py
def outer(inner_fun):
    def outer_inner(a, b):
        print("outer")
        inner_fun(a, b)
    return outer_inner

@outer
def inner(a, b):
    print("inner")
    print(a, b)

inner(1, 2)
```

This outputs:

```py
outer
inner
1 2
```

When we call `inner(1, 2)` first `inner` is given to `outer`. `outer` returns a function `outer_inner` where `inner_fun` is now set to `inner`. If there were another decorator (like in your example) the next decorator would be called with `outer_inner` as argument.
But because there is no further decorator, `outer_inner` is being called with the arguments `(1, 2)` which prints `"outer"` and calls the function `inner` (because `inner_fun` is set to `inner`). Then the function `inner` prints `"inner"` and the two numbers.

So in general: the outermost decorator is called first and then the inner decorators are called in their respective order.